# Value not showing for input field using one way binding angular2

Tags: html, typescript, angular2-forms

Objective: Get a collection of values based on the dropdown selection and place them in hidden input fields to be included in my model;

The relative html:

```html
<select class="selectFoo" (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)" name="FooName" ngModel>
            <option selected="selected">--Select--</option>
            <option *ngFor="let foo of foos" [value]="foo.ID">{{foo.Name}}
</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" [value]="fooAddress" name="FooAddress" ngModel/>
```

In the code above I called a function named OnSelect to get the data about the selected foo. The foos are populated using a webservice call. Here is the snippet from my ts file.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Foo } from './model';

import { DataService } from './data.service';


@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'add-on',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  foos : Foo[];

  selectedFoo: Foo;
  fooAddress: string;

  onSelect(fooID){
      this.selectedFoo = null;
      for(var i = 0; i < this.foos.length; i++)
      {
        console.log(this.foos[i].ID);
        if(this.foos[i].ID == fooID){
          this.selectedFoo = this.foos[i];
          this.fooAddress = this.selectedFoo.Address.toString();
        }
      }
    }
   }
```

I originally tried one way binding my value to the selectedFoo but I was getting an error indicating my Address value wasn't defined. I noticed I could set the value equal to selectedFoo and it didn't error. So i created a new variable that was set to the fooAddress based on the selected foo. I get no value even though while stepping through the code I see it has a value.

How can I get my value to populate so I can use it in my model? Let me know if I need to provide anything else.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am correctly understanding what you are after then something like this would work:

```
<select name="FooName" [(ngModel)]="selectedFoo">
  <option>--Select--</option>
  <option *ngFor="let foo of foos" [ngValue]="foo" >{{foo.Name}}</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" [value]="selectedFoo?.Address" name="FooAddress" />

//Assuming your 'foo' items are e.g. { ID: 1, Name: 'Hello', Address: '123 Hello St'}
```

Here you can bind the `Address` property of the `selectedFoo` directly to your hidden input field, rather than needing to handle the `(change)` event.

Comment: That is awesome! Thank you. I ended up resolving this by using formgroup. That way I didn't have to create hidden fields and I can just populate my model freely. That was based on a suggestion of a friend. I wanted to see of there was a way that was relevant to this post. So thank you!

Comment: Great, no worries - yes I was unsure why you'd need hidden input fields, I hadn't used them in my recent work with Angular forms. Anyway glad you got it working!